# Plesk - Angular 8 Hosting

Tags: angular, hosting, plesk, plesk-onyx

"**404 Not Found" on all pages except start page.**"

First page only working. Remaining pages all 404 error

If I run below structure url is working. 
[https://abcd.xyz](https://abc.xyz)

If I run below structure url is not working
https://abcd.xyz/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try useHash property in RouterModule

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256417/node-js-rest-api-not-working-plesk-hosting-server

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but if you're hosting your website on Linux you need to create a ".htaccess" file and paste inside it the following:

```
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
           RewriteEngine On             
           RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
           RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d    
           RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
           RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
       </IfModule>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).